# String slicing and iteration

Tags: string, substring

I'm kind of new to Python and I have a question:

In the following code I need to iterate and print the string backwards and normally like so: "deRRed"

```
# Mirror Color
# [ ] get user input, fav_color
# [ ] print fav_color backwards + fav_color
# example: "Red" prints "deRRed"

fav_color = input("What is your favorite color? ")

for letter in fav_color[::-1]:
    print(letter,fav_color)
```

I can get it to print, but I can't get deRRed or neerGGreen on one line.
How can I get it to print on one line? The code output looks like this:

---

```
What is your favorite color? red
d red
e red
r red
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the reverse iterated string in other variable and after that:

```
fav_color=input("enter your favourite color ")
new=" "
for a in fav_color[::-1]:
    new=new+a
print(new+fav_color)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fav_color = input("what is your fav color?")

print(fav_color[::-1]+fav_color)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the entire input string for each letter in the backwards string. Instead, first print the backwards string, and then the regular string:

```
print(fav_color[::-1] + color)
```

or if you need to print character by character:

```
for letter in fav_color[::-1] + fav_color:
    print(letter, end='')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fav_color = input("What is your favoutite color")

for letter in fav_color[::-1]:

print(fav_color[::-1] + fav_color)
```

Output is the following:

> What is your favoutite color: Green
>
> neerGGreen
>
> neerGGreen
>
> neerGGreen
>
> neerGGreen
>
> neerGGreen